# Why do we need a CPU clock

Tags: cpu, process, computer-architecture, clock, clockspeed

I'm very confused regarding the working of a cpu clock.The following questions arise in my mind-
What is the need of a clock in a cpu ?
 What does synchronization mean in context of working of a cpu ?
How many instructions can be executed in one cycle ?
Can more than one instruction be executed in one cpu cycle ?
Please explain these concepts using an example, such as addition or multiplication of numbers(or any other complex one) clearly mentioning the various instructions and cycles in which they are performed.

Comment: Way way to large a question. I suggest read a book on this subject (or multiple books).

Comment: Ok but atleast answer my these small questions :) .

Comment: Vote to close as "Too broad"

Comment: Don't cross-post!!  You asked essentially the same question on electronics.stackexchange.com an hour after this one.  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209378/significance-of-a-cpu-clock

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1)** Basically a CPU's clock keeps everything in the CPU synchronized.

CPUs are digital and like anything else digital, they work on the principle of "on" and "off" - however, transistors take time to fully switch on or off, and if you check for the state of one while it is transitioning, you will get unpredictable results.  With a clock signal, we have something that says "by this deadline, this signal should be valid."  The other option is to have a second signal that says "I'm done, this signal is now valid" and I think that makes circuits much more complex.

**2)** [Go here for the second answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization) Informative, Illustrative and easy to understand.

**3)** [Go here for the third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle#Calculation_of_IPC)

**4)** [The Fourth](https://www.quora.com/How-could-a-CPU-execute-more-than-one-instruction-per-clock-cycle) Very complicated, I say.

*AND PLEASE Don't ask so long questions, that is why I gave you links.*

Comment: Thanks alot for these informative links. Now only one question I'd like to ask is "does every instruction takes the same amount of time/cycle or it also depends on the type of processor ? "

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal I will give you the answer but can you please accept my answer please... If you liked it. You can edit it by opening your post and clicking the empty 'tick' icon on the left side of my answer.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal I will research and give you the answer

Comment: I will surely once you give me the answer, or if u assure that you will surely  give me the answer

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal I can give you a link about this topic will that be okay?

Comment: Yea that will be great, and I will be waiting for the answer.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction) is the first link.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal i will research more and give you more informations. Thank you for accepting my answer

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. The question has been closed as too broad and shouldn't have been answered.

Comment: @BhanuKumar - In the future do the research before you submit your answer.  You should make an effort to do things right the first time, every time, otherwise your answers will be deleted for quality control reasons by the community.

Answer (score 1):

*What is the need of a clock in a cpu ?*
=> CPU is a sequencial machine, one tick, one cyle, one operation/ task/ job

*What does synchronization mean in context of working of a cpu ?*
=> too many things depending on the context, rougly it ensures that information has properly propageted before the next task started

*How many instructions can be executed in one cycle ?*
=> it depends on the architecture of the CPU

*Can more than one instruction be executed in one cpu cycle ?*
=> yes but, it depends on CPU architecture

as said above, there is plenty good books about that,

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). Also "does every instruction takes the same amount of time/cycle or it also depends on the type of processor ? "